# How to linkify number in intput error message of TextInputLayout?

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

[image]

As shown in the picture, i want to linkify the number show in error message.
I have already tried below code:
`SpannableString s = new SpannableString(errorText);
s.setSpan(new TypeFaceSpan(font), 0, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS);`

So this code highlights the number but clicking on it doesnt open the dialer.

Any suggestions will be really helpful.

Comment: Random idea: do you have a way to listen for those click events. For example, do you have a click listener for the TextView containing the phone number?